# How do you get AWS SDK to obtain a role when signing in from Azure AD SSO (Enterprise Application) redirected via Relay State?

Tags: javascript, azure, single-sign-on, aws-sdk, saml

I'm working on allowing the AWS SDK to access AWS resources from the browser. I'm using Azure AD Idp-initiated Enterprise Applications flow. The Consuming service is signin.aws.amazom.com/saml and the Relay state is set to https://region.console.aws.amazon.com/connect/federate/instance?destination=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite123.edu .
I'm using Amazon Connect for relay (notice /connect/federate/ ), as I also need to sign in to Connect on the same webpage (website123.edu) . The problem is, after the redirect to website123 I can't get the AWS SDK in website123 code to call anything, because it is missing credentials. Somehow, the redirect should have logged me in to AzureAD, I assume by giving me a token (once again, where can I find it?), or maybe aws gave me a token or role when redirecting from console.aws.amazon.com/connect/federate. AssumeRoleWithSAML (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRoleWithSAML-property) seems to be a solution, though I still don't know where I would find the SAML assertion from the website code.

So my question is, after I sign in with Azure AD IDP, and it redirects me to a website, where do I get the token for AzureAD, and where/how do I get the token for a Role/Permissions to access AWS?

Max

I tried seeing the requests that come through the browser, through the network tab, and pressing preserve log. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_saml_view-saml-response.html
Through this, I've found on the saml response:
Set-Cookie: aws-creds=...
Set-Cookie: aws-userInfo-Signed=ey... (JSON Web Token) which had a visitor-id and expiry time set to 1hr.

I'm assuming I can use these somehow...